# Is it possible that call javascript function based on PHP CURL request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, php-curl

I want to call javascript function when from CURL request using Codeigniter. Basically i want to trigger notification in browser when data entered in DB. So when Data enter then i use CURL request and load one page, and in that page i want to call trigger notification function. I have tried below but didn't work.

**PHP Code For Curl Request**

```
$post = $_POST;

        $url = str_replace('/ws/'.APP_VERSION,'',site_url('mydomain/notification_update'));
       $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);
```

**Another PHP page which call based on CURL request**

```
public function notification_update() {
        $post = $_POST;
        $this->load->view('header', $post, FALSE);

    }
```

**View Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var w_type = '<?= (isset($w_type) && $w_type == 'for_window_noty') ? $w_type : '' ?>';
            console.log('w_type', w_type);
          if(w_type) {
                console.log('succes test');
          }


</script>
```

I have place here just javascript code for view page.

Note: my post param is `w_type = for_window_noty`

Comment: What value does the script w_type var get when php is done outputting the page?

Comment: i want to generate notification when getting curl request, so i will call another ajax when getting curl request. i know i can do it by calling ajax on some interval but it will give too much load to server. so i just want to call ajax when actual data enter in DB.

Comment: @James value is like w_type = for_window_noty

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up websockets to prevent ajax polling load

Comment: @charlietfl yes i can use socket but it is easy with node.js but i think socket is not that much easy with PHP.

Comment: Have you researched that or is that simply a guess?

Comment: @charlietfl i have done websocket with use of socket.io with sails js. but i have research about php and did not getting any good option for the same.

Comment: Did you try Ratchet?

Comment: @charlietfl no i have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Server Sent Events**

Use an event listener to listen for [Server Sent Events](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/).

When triggered, show your message.

It uses an event source

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('stream.php')
} else {
  // Result to xhr polling :(
}
```

That you can listen to

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data)
}, false)
```

**WebSockets API**

Another way would be to use the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

WebSockets allow for two-way communication between client and server.

It comes at the cost of being a bit heavier to implement.

Comment: and for server side?

Comment: Implementations server side are not standardised, but there are libraries available. A quick google search brought me to https://github.com/hhxsv5/php-sse, which shows and example for PHP generic, as well as Symfony/Laravel. Of course this is not the only library availailable and you should pick what suits your needs best.